# Nodejs how to set content-type header for every request

Tags: node.js, http, header

I would like to know how I can set the header `"Content-Type": "application/json"` for every nodejs express request that comes in.

I tried both of these lines but my calls are still failing if I don't add the header myself:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    req.header("Content-Type", "application/json");
    res.header("Content-Type", "application/json");
    next();
});
```

All of my requests are json, so I don't want the front end (Anguler) to send me this header every time if I can just set it myself from the server side.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Response object has to use `.setHeader` instead of `.header`:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    next();
});
```

[doc.](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_request_setheader_name_value)

Answer (score 2):

Send headers as an object:

```js
res.writeHead(200, {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Content-Length": "1234...",
});
```

Here you have to also specify status code, `200` means Status is `OK`, learn more about status codes here : [HTTP Status Codes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status)

or use this code to set individual headers

```js
res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
res.setHeader("Content-Length", "1234...");
```

Answer (score 1):

To update the request headers please add below custom middleware before bodyparser

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  req.headers['content-type'] = 'application/json';
  next();
});
```

If still not working check the case of 'content-type' sent by your client. Put the 'content-type' in the same case