# Problem when converting the output of Fetch to string (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I have a txt file containing a list of all Italian words ([link](http://doodlemarty.unaux.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/parole.txt)) that I want to read and then convert to an array of words, but I'm a bit stuck on the reading part. The file was originally downloaded from the web, so it might or might not have some encoding issues.

To read the file, I am using Fetch, with the same code suggested in the top answer of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39758031/get-text-from-a-txt-file-in-the-url). After reading it, if I use `alert(storedText)` the text is correctly displayed; however, if I try `var s = storedText.toString()` and then `alert(s)` I get "undefined" in the alert box.

I guess there is some problem when reading the file, but I'm rather new to JavaScript and I can't figure out what exactly the problem is. Do you guys have any idea?

Edit: this is my full code

```js
var storedText;

fetch('http://doodlemarty.unaux.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/parole.txt')
  .then(function(response) {
response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    response.text().then(function(text) {
      storedText = text;
      done();
    });
  });

var s = storedText.toString();
var fullList = storedText.split('\n');

function test () {
//first try:
alert(storedText);
//second try:
alert(s);
//trying split:
alert(fullList[2]);
  };
```

I have the test function execute when a button is clicked.

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: Why do you need toString on it? It is already a string. Do a storedText.split(/\s+/) to get the words. Make sure it is UTF8 and the page that runs it has meta tag for UTF8 too

Comment: My feeling is that your first `alert` was within the promise's `then` handler but the second one was outside, running too early, in which case this would be a duplicate of [this good old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call), but we can't tell without seeing the code.

Comment: @mplungjan I tried using toString because I was having issues with the split method (I was getting an "undefined")

Comment: @Martina it'd be good to see that too

Comment: @evolutionxbox ok, I've added that too!

Comment: That text list resource requires a computed cookie in order to be accessed. Otherwise, you just get html informing you that you need JS.

Comment: Change `function test () {` to `function test (storedtext) {` and change `done()` to `test(storedText)`

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a `async` issue with promises. You are trying to access `storedText` before its value is updated in the `fetch` operation.

Try this:

```
var storedText;
var s;
var fullList;

async function callFetch() {
    let response = await fetch('http://doodlemarty.unaux.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/parole.txt')
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    let text = await response.text();
    storedText = text;
}

function setVariables() {
    s = storedText.toString();
    fullList = storedText.split('\n');
}

async function test() {
    await callFetch();
    setVariables();
    //first try:
    alert(storedText);
    //second try:
    alert(s);
    //trying split:
    alert(fullList[2]);
};
```

Comment: No need for all that async, just move processing where the data arrives

Comment: Yes @mplungjan, that is the idea. In the simplest terms, just process the data after you get it from API. It was just my opinion that async looks more readable.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked! Anyway, in order to make it work I have to remove the line where response.setContentType is called... Any idea why? (I have already noticed the missing semicolon in the first line of callFetch and fixed it)

Comment: `setContentType` is not supported according to the spec: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response
https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#response-class  

It's a server side operation (if you are using node in backend, refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52812561/nodejs-how-to-set-content-type-header-for-every-request)

Comment: @stWrong oh ok, thank you!